# Purpose of stickers copying license plate number?

Tags: public-transport, driving, peru

On every seemingly 'official' taxi and bus in Peru (including vans and minibuses that seem to be owned by local travel agencies) you see copies of the license plate numbers painted on the vehicles;
usually in the form of stickers but I have seen hand-painted signs on old taxis:

[image]

[image]

**What purpose do these serve?**
Some bureacratic proof of licensing, anti-theft measures, ...?
Do they mean anything for me as a traveler, i.e are they supposed to guarantee something?

Notes:

- Private individuals playing taxi don't have them
- I have seen two repair(?) service cars from private companies with these stickers as well

Comment: In Kuwait, all public vehicles have the same vehicle number as the license plate number; so its also painted on the car. Here it is to track vehicles and also to prevent fraud.

Answer (score 5):

Most countries that require such do it a means of readily identifying a vehicle.  No matter which door you get out you can see the taxi's license number.  A lot of countries require the same info posted inside the cab.

Comment: Similar markings are found on New York City cabs

Comment: And on Russian trucks. And at times on other trucks as well, some companies use it as a vehicle ID in lue of inventing their own system.